# Execution By Hanging

Tags: tenses

When referring to execution by hanging, it is grammatically correct to say:

> The offender is to be hanged.

Instead of:

> The offender is to be hung.

When referring to historic methods of execution, why would we say:

> The offender is to be hung, drawn and quartered.

Instead of:

> The offender is to be hanged, drawn and quartered.

The latter doesn't sound right, but is it, or isn't it grammatically correct?

Comment: Have you checked a dictionary or usage guide? This issue is discussed by many websites, books, etc. Are you interested in some aspect of this issue that they don't discuss?

Comment: There's a general trend for irregular verbs to be "regularized", but it this case the "executed by hanging" sense has shifted in recent decades [*from regular **hanged** to irregular **hung***](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hung+drawn+and+quartered%2Changed+drawn+and+quartered&year_start=1850&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20) for a usage that we might have *expected* to be a fixed "frozen form" anyway...

Comment: ...but that [*hasn't happened*](https://books.google.com/ngrams/graph?content=hanged+by+the+neck+until%2Chung+by+the+neck+until&year_start=1860&year_end=2019&corpus=en-2019&smoothing=20) with the other common expression in this area - ***hanged** by the neck until dead*.

Answer (score 3):

***Hang*** is one of those strange verbs that have similar-looking roots, past tenses and participles, (such as "lie" and "lay") that have different meanings depending on the context and tense.

As far as I know, the participle *hanged* has been reserved for those poor wretches who die at the end of a noose, while *hung*  could refer to a painting on a wall, or even those criminals who have had their bits and pieces displayed in the town square of a medieval village as a warning.

[Merriam-Webster:](https://www.merriam-webster.com/words-at-play/hung-or-hanged)

> ...most usage guides reserve hanged for people subjected to death, which means if an inanimate object is suspended from a gallows, the correct term is hung

Comment: The hanging part was until-not-quite-dead, if I remember (and was taught) correctly. So one might expect 'hanged, drawn and quartered'. // In fact, [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanged,_drawn_and_quartered) shows both variants.

Comment: Consider asking for your [two accounts](https://english.stackexchange.com/users/479845/rattler) to be [merged](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/18232/how-can-one-link-merge-combine-associate-two-accounts-users-anonymous).

Comment: @EdwinAshworth AFAIK, when in reference to torture and execution during the middle ages, _hung_ meant the actually hanging from  a battlement whilst being "drawn", and after that taken down "quartered" and beheaded. Not a nice way to die.

Comment: @Cascabel [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hanged,_drawn_and_quartered) has 'To be hanged, drawn and quartered became a statutory penalty for men convicted of high treason in the Kingdom of England... The convicted traitor was fastened to a hurdle, or wooden panel, and drawn by horse to the place of execution, where he was then hanged (almost to the point of death) ....' The second article adds 'The past and past participle of 'hang' in this sense is 'hanged' rather than 'hung'.'

Comment: @EdwinAshworth I noticed that in some language of the period, "hanged" is used in places where we might use "hung" today. Ex. ["....and there  hanged  long time after"](https://www.google.com.gt/books/edition/The_Annales_of_England_Faithfully_Collec/c0NoAAAAcAAJ?hl=en&gbpv=1&dq=%22%22hanged%22&pg=PA968&printsec=frontcover)